# Update error message

Tags: spotify

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 13B00F1FD2C19886
W: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/InRelease  
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

How can I fix spotify?

Answer (score 4):

> "
>   By far the simplest way to handle this now is with Y-PPA-Manager (which now integrates the `launchpad-getkeys` script with a graphical interface).
>
> 1. To install it, first add the webupd8 repository for this program:
>
>    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
> 2. Update your software list and install Y-PPA-Manager:
>
>    sudo apt-get update
>          sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
> 3. Run y-ppa-manager (i.e. type `y-ppa-manager` then press enter key).
> 4. When the main y-ppa-manager window appears, click on "Advanced."
> 5. From the list of advanced tasks, select "Try to import all missing GPG keys" and click OK.
>
> You're done! As the warning dialog says when you start the operation, it may take quite a while (about 2 minutes for me) depending on how many PPA's you have and the speed of your connection.
>   "

--[How do I fix the GPG error "NO_PUBKEY"?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13065/how-do-i-fix-the-gpg-error-no-pubkey)